# Conectar com o banco de dados usando .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core

estou estudando .Net Core 2 e não estou conseguindo fazer a conexão com o banco de dados.

Meu appsettings.json está assim:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
     "DefaultConnection": "Server=FAYOL\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Pagamento;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

E o Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Repository; 
namespace Radix
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

        var connection = @"Server=FAYOL\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Pagamento;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        services.AddDbContext<Contexto>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    }
}
```

}

Não estou sabendo fazer como apontar o `Startup.cs` para o Json e como fazer isso. Peguei um exemplo na internet q coloca a string direto no `ConfigureServices` (como o exemplo acima) e está dando erro.

Conseguem me ajudar?

Obrigado

Comment: Olá Thiago, na sua classe Startup no construtor dela insira: 

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

E depois no ConfigureServices:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddDbContext<DbContextIdentity>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            services.AddMvc();

        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recuperar a string de conexão do `appsettings.json` você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Repository; 
namespace Radix
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            string connecttionStringV2 = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["DefaultConnection"];
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<Contexto>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi Barbetta, eu tentei dessa forma Tentei dessa forma, mas diz que Configuration.GetConnectionString não existe no contexto.

Se usar o Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration não existe o metodo GetConnectionString e o mesmo vale para o System.Configuration.

Comment: Favor, adicione na pergunta a sua startup inteira, até os `using's`

Comment: Classe completa na pergunta.  :)

Comment: @ThiagoRodolfo atualizei, acho que sem querer você apagou o construtor.

Comment: Oi Barbetta, obrigado pela elegância em mostrar meu erro, de fato eu apaguei sem prestar atenção em que estava fazendo. :) 

Outra dúvida, a linha : 
string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); está retornando null, o Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); não acha essa string e ele parece não está achando o appsettings.json.

Comment: Resolvido! Aparentemente o meu Program.cs estava errado. Agora está assim:

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }


        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }

Comment: aah sim, de todo modo adicionei uma segunda forma de chamar a string de conexão na pergunta

Comment: Me da um outro help por favor. Quando executo a aplicação vai para a url: http://localhost:52692/api/values e da o seguinte erro: Não foi possível encontrar a página deste localhost. Quando mando pra url do meu controller http://localhost:52692/api/AdquirenteController/get continua o erro. Debuguei o Startup.cs e o Program.cs e não da erro em lugar nenhum, preciso configurar mais alguma coisa?

Comment: Tenta assim http://localhost:52692/api/Adquirente/Get, apesar dos controllers terem 'controller' no nome não é necessário passar isso nas rotas

Comment: Obrigado Barbetta! Tudo funcionando perfeitamente agora.